# How to troubleshoot the initial setup of hardware on a new computer?

Tags: windows, video, motherboard

I just bought a computer and it was working fine (without an OS) at the shop after the guy helped me to configure it.

When I reached home, the computer is unable to output anything through my graphics card, monitor displaying no video, but the fan and GPU's fan is spinning. No POST beeps either.

Tested by removing the ram, and I heard the beep sound, so I believe the motherboard is still alright.

Another thing I noticed is that at initial power up each time, the computer will power up for like 10-20 sec before it auto restarts. But after the initial restart, it does not seem to restart a second time, but still without video.

On the motherboard, there a 2 led, 1 green and 1 red. Not sure if this means anything.

Can anyone advise me on how to test? It's not convenient for me to go down to the shop until the weekend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to help you without more information, but this is one of the problems I dread and have only personally had it on Gigabyte motherboards.

The problem usually comes down to one of the following (which always clear it for me):

1. Unseat everything you can, other than the CPU.... Doesn't matter how well you think you did it, there could be a problem.
2. Swap memory modules around... Again, you can have two completely perfect, working memory modules, but the moo may not like them, swapping can fix and you can even swap back (after a successful boot).
3. Always last, it could be a genuine error such as the power unit is too low for your current configuration - especially as you talk about your own graphics card. I recommend you try to read up the specifications of your card and possibly get higher if you have a funky setup with extra hard/optical drives.

Comment: my case wise is a Asus motherboard, a P series. But I don't have the exact model as I'm working and the invoice is at home. Power unit wise, I don't think personally it's low. Should be more than enough, seek recommendation from those guys assembling. Will try to see if I can calculate it out.

Comment: In the urgent need for my com, i did as what u say, reseating all the parts. It ended up well. Thanks